# how do I make an invisible table with 1 column at the left and 2 columns at the right using html, css or js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

`#right` is the div that needs to be in the right column and its height must be the same as the sum of `#leftbottom`'s height and `#lefttop`'s height (left column).

The following HTML is just an example:

```css
#right {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 10px;
  border-color: darkorange;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
}

#leftbottom,
#lefttop {
  background-image: url(images/backgrnd2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 102% 100%;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div id="right">
    <a>HOME</a>
    <p>FEATURED THEORY OF THE DAY:</p>
    <p>AREA 51<br/>Why the government hide us the truth behind these?</p>
    <a>Continue reading>>></a>
    <p>IS THIS REALLY TRUE?</p>
    <p>THE HOLLOW EARTH, AGHARTA<br/>Know more about the center of the Earth and what is inside of it?</p>
    <a>Continue reading>>></a>
    <p>THEORETICAL EXPLANATION:</p>
    <p>SPONGEBOB SQUAREPANTS AND THE SEVEN DEADLY SINS<br/>Help us ruin your childhood with this theory.</p>
    <a>Continue reading>>></a>
    <p>PLAY WITH YOUR BRAIN!</p>
    <p>CRIME LOGIC<br/>Who kill the innocent victim?</p>
    <a>Continue reading>>></a>
    <p>STORIES FOR LIFE</p>
    <p>HOW I SURVIVE MIDDLE SCHOOL?<br/>May these be an inspiration for us.</p>
    <a>Continue reading>>></a>
  </div>
  <div id="lefttop">
    <h1>Timeline of Posts:</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>2017</li>
      <li>2016</li>
      <li>2015</li>
      <li>2014</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="leftbottom">
    <h1>Featured Article:</h1>
    <p><a>Spongebob Theory</a></p>
    <p><a>Area 51</a></p>
    <p><a>Aliens</a></p>
    <p><a>Phineas and Ferb Theory</a></p>
    <p><a>Cartoon Theories</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by the height of left column?

Comment: The height of the right is the same as the height of the left divs combined. So, they will align nicely. The 1st column takes up 2 rows and the 2nd column has 2 rows.

Comment: content in your right div is more, it will have more height. Do you want it to scroll?

Comment: Thanks, but no. I don't need it to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `float:right` in `#right`

```css
#right {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 10px;
  border-color: darkorange;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  float: right;
}

#leftbottom,
#lefttop {
  background-image: url(images/backgrnd2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 102% 100%;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div id="right">
    <a>HOME</a>
    <p>FEATURED THEORY OF THE DAY:</p>
    <p>AREA 51<br/>Why the government hide us the truth behind these?</p>
    <a>Continue reading>>></a>
    <p>IS THIS REALLY TRUE?</p>
    <p>THE HOLLOW EARTH, AGHARTA<br/>Know more about the center of the Earth and what is inside of it?</p>
    <a>Continue reading>>></a>
    <p>THEORETICAL EXPLANATION:</p>
    <p>SPONGEBOB SQUAREPANTS AND THE SEVEN DEADLY SINS<br/>Help us ruin your childhood with this theory.</p>
    <a>Continue reading>>></a>
    <p>PLAY WITH YOUR BRAIN!</p>
    <p>CRIME LOGIC<br/>Who kill the innocent victim?</p>
    <a>Continue reading>>></a>
    <p>STORIES FOR LIFE</p>
    <p>HOW I SURVIVE MIDDLE SCHOOL?<br/>May these be an inspiration for us.</p>
    <a>Continue reading>>></a>
  </div>
  <div id="lefttop">
    <h1>Timeline of Posts:</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>2017</li>
      <li>2016</li>
      <li>2015</li>
      <li>2014</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="leftbottom">
    <h1>Featured Article:</h1>
    <p><a>Spongebob Theory</a></p>
    <p><a>Area 51</a></p>
    <p><a>Aliens</a></p>
    <p><a>Phineas and Ferb Theory</a></p>
    <p><a>Cartoon Theories</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I use 'float: left' instead, will it just switch it?

Comment: Yup, I have another html file that has this same scenario but their places needs to be switched. The '#right' needs to be on the left and '#lefttop' and '#leftbottom' needs to be on the right

Comment: whichever needs to be on the right, use float:right for that.

Comment: So I'd use 'float:right' to '#lefttop' and '#leftbottom' but it won't disturb the placement of other divs?

Comment: will need to check rest of the html code to answer that for sure.

Comment: I tried to do it but what happens is that '#lefttop' and '#leftbottom' aligns horizontally instead of vertically

Comment: then wrap lefttop and leftbottom in a div and give float to that div